# How to calculate a matrix formed by vector in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to obtain a matrix `vvT` formed by a column vector `v`. i.e. the column vector `v` matrix times its transpose.

I found Mathematica doesn't support column vector. Please help.

Comment: Qiang Li, please join us on the new site:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Mr.W's answered your problem, but just to clarify: a column vector is a 1*n matrix and a row vector is a n*1 matrix. Then the [outer product](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html) that you're looking for is just matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
v = List /@ Range@5;
vT = Transpose[v];
vvT = v.vT;

v // MatrixForm
vT // MatrixForm
vvT // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` into `{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}` you can use any of:

```
List /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

{ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} }\[Transpose]

Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 1]
```

You may find one of these more convenient than the others.  Usually on long lists you will find `Partition` to be the fastest.

Also, your specific operation can be done in different ways:

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Outer[Times, x, x]
```

Syntactically shortest:

[image: {Range@5}; %[Transpose].%]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @QiangLi okay, then I will update my answer with a couple of useful tips.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Why is `v = List /@ Range@5;` a column vector but not a row vector in matrix form? As i know every vector is row vector in Mathematica by default.

Comment: @kww By wrapping each element in `List` we get `{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}` and by *Mathematica* convention this is a matrix of five rows each containing a single element.  It is my understanding that there really isn't such a thing as a column vector in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, so `List` does not produce `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` but `{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}`? In this case I understand why the matrix form returns a column vector.